# how does vector::erase remove the chosen element from it's internal array

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

Since an object of type vector is internally backed by an array, how does the erase function of the vector class remove the chosen element from it's internal array?

I am looking for an in depth explanation with at least a basic code example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By copying the elements after the erased element, and then filling with an "empty" element at the end. And then marks the size as one less.

Roughly the code would be like this [the ACTUAL implementation will be using tricks to avoid making unnecessary copies and such, for example using move-semantics]

```
template<typename T>std::vector::erase(int index)
{
   // Call destructor of T for the one being deleted.
   storage[index].T~();
   for(i = index; i < size-1; i++)
   {
       storage[i] = storage[i+1];
   }
   storage[size-1] = T();
   size--;
}
```

If you want to see how the REAL implementation works, I suggest you fire up the debugger, and try it out yourself. But don't be surprised if it's horribly complex and hard to understand - people who write library code are typically very well versed in how the language works, and will use "any trick in the book" to make it faster/smaller/neater.

Comment: That makes sense. Would you mind providing a very basic example in code, reading code just helps me fully grasp concepts.

Comment: Also, when you say that the array is filled with an 'empty' element, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: If you have a `std::vector<T> v; ... v.erase();` then the operation, after "shuffling" will be `v[size-1] = T();` [or something equivalent].

Comment: No, it will call the destructor on the object.

Comment: destructor call added.

Comment: I realize it's just pseudocode, but you destruct an object and then invoke its assignment operator.

Comment: Yeah, I believe the actual code will swap the last and the actual element, and then destroy the element at the end. But I did TRY to say that "this is just to illustrate how it works, and if you want to see how it's actually done, try stepping through with a debugger".

Answer (score 2):

When removing any element other than the one at the end, the elements after the one removed would be shuffled left.

Comment: All it would involve is a loop shuffling, possibly destroying the last element (which is no longer needed), and reducing the recorded size by 1.    Various optimisations possible depending on the type of element, but that's the basic concept.

Answer (score 2):

The vector has to allocate memory without calling any constructors yet. Then it may use *placement new* and *placement delete* (aka. manually calling the destructor).

*Placement new* involves specifying a memory address, and invoking the constructor with `this` pointing to that memory address.  *Placement delete* involves running the destructor, but not freeing the memory. (The vector will hold onto the memory block and then placement-new another object into the same location).

The vector may also use the *copy-assignment operator*, *copy constructor*, *move constructor*, *move-assignment operator* to do its job.

Prior to C++11, vectors required the elements to be CopyAssignable, so a basic vector implementation (obviously I have omitted many functions):

```
template<typename T>
struct vector
{
    T *base;
    size_t m_count;
    size_t m_capacity;

    // start off with space reserved for 20 elements, but no actual elements
    vector(): base((T *)new unsigned char[20 * sizeof(T)]), 
              m_count(0), m_capacity(20) {}

    void push_back(T const &t) {
        if ( m_count == m_capacity )
             reserve(m_capacity * 2);

        // placement new, using copy-constructor
        new(base + m_count) T(t);
        ++m_count;
    }

    void erase(size_t index)
    {
    // Use the assignment-operator to shuffle all objects down by one
    // (The "being erased" object doesn't get destructed directly, but it
    //  loses its state by having another object assigned to it. This is
    //  permitted because T must be CopyAssignable prior to C++11. In
    //  C++11 this function would try to Move objects down instead.
         for (size_t i = index; i < m_count - 1; ++i)
             base[i] = base[i+1];

    // Call destructor for the last object (which we currently have 2 of)
         base[m_count-1].~T();
         --m_count;

    }
};
```